# Hacer una consulta a la BD con un Json - Laravel

Tags: laravel, array, json, base-de-datos, update

Cordial saludo tengo una duda de como poder actualizar la base de datos con un Json.
Me solicitaron un requerimiento de poder actualizar varias registros a la vez así que lo que se me ocurrió fue crear un Array y con los datos seleccionados obtener su id y así hacer una consulta a la base de datos y actualizarlos no se si sea la mejor manera de hacerlo pero soy nuevo en lo que es programación .
lo realizado hasta el momento:
tengo mi controlador donde llamo a mi array y hago un foreach para obtener los id de los datos seleccionados del array y me funciona obtengo los id como se observa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function sub_update(){
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    foreach($cart as $test) {
        $result[] =  $test['id'];
    }
    dd($result);
    //$test_consult = DB::table('servicios')->where('id',$result)->get();
    //dd($test_consult);
}
```

Pero cuando quiero hacer la consulta a la base de datos solo me muestra solo un registro es decir que solo toma al primer id que es '3'

```
 public function sub_update(){
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    foreach($cart as $test) {
        $result[] =  $test['id'];
    }
    //dd($result);
    $test_consult = DB::table('servicios')->where('id',$result)->get();
    dd($test_consult);
}
```

No se si lo que estoy haciendo esta bien pero agradecería mucho de su ayuda

Comment: tienes que cambiar tu where a un whereIn y listo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda